# Matlab image translation matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm very new to Matlab. I'm learning some image manipulation basics, and I'm a bit confused on how to write a translation *without using imtranslate*.

this is my code but it just displays a black background. Thank you.

```
img = imread('name2.png');
figure(1);

% pixel matrix
[orig_x, orig_y,z] = size(img); 

final_x = 600;                      
final_y = 600;                     

% define the final array with calculated dimensions and fill the array with zeros ie.,black
final_img = uint8(zeros([final_x final_y 3 ]));

for i = 1 : size(final_img, 1)
    for j = 1 : size(final_img, 2)        
          new_x = img(i) + 5;
          new_y = img(j) + 5;

         % fprintf('X: %f\n',new_x); % prints 255

        final_img(i) = new_x;
        final_img(j) = new_y;

    end
end

imshow(final_img);
```

Comment: Are you trying to translate the image, or resize it? Where do you define `rads`? I suspect that a large part of your problem is that you're addressing 3d arrays as though they were 1d, e.g. `new_x = img(i)`.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake while copying the code from the editor. Now it's correct. The idea is to translate the image by 5 on both axis. Thanks

Comment: The black image seems to be a contrast problem. Try `imshow(final_img, [])`. But you have some other mistakes in the code. First, beaker's point. Second, you change the image values in spite of image positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution for 'translation only' transformation.

```
I  = imread('Lenna.png');
shiftX = 5; % shift columns
shiftY = 5; % shift rows

% Assigning empty matrix for result, expected to be shiftX-1 larger in rows and shiftY-1 larger in columns
nI = uint8( zeros(size(I,1)+shiftY-1, size(I,2)+shiftX-1, size(I,3));

% Translate 
nI(shiftY:end, shiftX:end, :)  = I;
imshow(nI)
```

Now the image will start from `(x,y) = (5,5) instead of (1,1)`. Also note that in matlab image coordinate system, x and y axis start from upper left corner ([documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html)).

Comment: can you please clarify  this line? nI(shiftY:end, shiftX:end, :)  = I;

Comment: I thought about going through each pixel with a for loop is more useful (especially when I'll have to add other transformations like rotation)

Comment: The line means : In the new image nI , extract the  submatrix from rows=5:end and columns=5:end for all 3 color channels (ie the last :) and set it to the same value as I. 
You can easily rotate using inbuilt imrotate() OR convolve the image with a corresponding rotation matrix of SO(3) group. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rotation_matrix
Per pixel looping is generally not favoured as it is very inefficient, especially if you only plan to do simple transformations like translation and rotation. Looping is ok if complex non-linear function estimates need to be computed at each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

1. final_img:

You've defined "final_img" with new x and new y but you haven't replaced the zeros in the red/green/blue values. It's all black because of your initialisation filling the final_img with all zeros.

Maybe try this instead of what you've written:

```
%{
[X,map] = imread('name2.png');
figure(1);

% X should be 600 by 600 

%Translate X however you wish, e.g.:
X = X +5;

%Verify that the colormap, map, is not empty, and convert 
%the data in X to RGB and store as your final_img.

if ~isempty(map)
    final_img = ind2rgb(X,map);
end
%}
```

2. I am also not sure if you want to be indexing img with just a single i without the the other dimensions like you have:
   new_x = img(i) + 5;
   ?

Answer (score 0):

For the problems in your specific code, I wrote in the comments some of them.
A short way to achieve image translation is by 2D convolution with a filter of zeros and just one `1`, that will preserve the values of the image, but relocate them according to the size of the filter and the position of the `1` in it.

That seems you want to move the image but preserve the size of the total image, if I get it right. So:

```
r=3; c=5;                                % number of rows and columns to move
filt=zeros(r*2+1, c*2+1); filt(end)=1;   % the filetr
img2=conv2(img,filt,'same');               % the translated image
```

Just for the example, lets translate "cameraman" with 20 rows and columns:

```
img=imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(img)
```

[image: cameraman]

```
r=20; c=20;                         
filt=zeros(r*2+1, c*2+1); filt(end)=1;
img2=conv2(img,filt,'same');
figure; imshow(img2,[])
```

[image: cameraman2]